# AVPlayer - Fast Backward / Forward Stream

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, avplayer, forward

This is my code in the viewDidLoad :

```
AVPlayerItem* playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://groove.wavestreamer.com:7321/listen.pls?sid=1"]];

[playerItem addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"timedMetadata" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];

music = [[AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem] retain];
[music play];
```

My question:
How can I create a button, that fast-forwards / fast-backwards the stream 5 seconds, when it´s pressed?

Thank you for your answers... :)

EDIT: How can I add to my current time...

```
CMTime currentTime = music.currentTime;
```

...the 5 seconds?

Comment: Is this the right way?  CMTime currentTime = music.currentTime;
    
    float audioCurrentSeconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(currentTime);
    audioCurrentSeconds += 5.0;
    
    [music seekToTime:audioCurrentSeconds toleranceBefore:kCMTimeZero toleranceAfter:kCMTimeZero];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use AVPlayer method `seekToTime`

```
AVPlayer *player=..;
 [player seekToTime:time toleranceBefore:kCMTimeZero toleranceAfter:kCMTimeZero];
```

here is a [reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Hope it helps

Comment: Forwarding is working perfectly, but I can´t rewind with this method. Do you know why?

Comment: What happens when you try to rewind?

Comment: You are probsbly giving the wrong time,  from what you display in your comment, you are giving it a int/float? it should be a CMTime struct

Comment: @Daniel how do you catch/detect the fast forward action?

Comment: @NorthBlast you need to make your own control, a scrub bar of some sort, when its slide up/back you act accordingly

Comment: @Daniel thanks man, I just was trying not to go through the painful way lol.. But, I guess I will have to.. lol..

Comment: @NorthBlast with a UISlider it should be real easy... it has a value of 0 to 1, seek time = FullMovieTime * Value which will give you the time you need to seek to

Comment: @Daniel, Could you please help me how can I do trick play speed in avplayer bro? Do you know how to implement it?

Answer (score 16):

**In Swift**,

```
fileprivate let seekDuration: Float64 = 5


@IBAction func doForwardJump(_ sender: Any) {
    guard let duration  = player.currentItem?.duration else{
        return
    }
    let playerCurrentTime = CMTimeGetSeconds(player.currentTime())
    let newTime = playerCurrentTime + seekDuration

    if newTime < CMTimeGetSeconds(duration) {

        let time2: CMTime = CMTimeMake(Int64(newTime * 1000 as Float64), 1000)
        player.seek(to: time2)
    }
}
@IBAction func doBackwardJump(_ sender: Any) {

    let playerCurrentTime = CMTimeGetSeconds(player.currentTime())
    var newTime = playerCurrentTime - seekDuration

    if newTime < 0 {
        newTime = 0
    }
    let time2: CMTime = CMTimeMake(Int64(newTime * 1000 as Float64), 1000)
    player.seek(to: time2)

}
```

**In Objective-C,**

```
#define seekDuration (float)5

- (IBAction)backwardButtonAction:(UIButton *)sender {
    float playerCurrentTime = [self getCurrentTime];
    float newTime = playerCurrentTime - seekDuration;

    if (newTime < 0) {
        newTime = 0;
    }
    CMTime time = CMTimeMake(newTime*1000, 1000);
    [self.player seekToTime:time completionHandler:^(BOOL finished) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            playerSliderisScrubbing = NO;
        });
    }];
}
- (IBAction)forwardButtonAction:(UIButton *)sender {
    float duration = [self getPlayerDuration];
    float playerCurrentTime = [self getCurrentTime];
    float newTime = playerCurrentTime + seekDuration;

    if (newTime < duration) {
        CMTime time = CMTimeMake(newTime*1000, 1000);
        [self.player seekToTime:time completionHandler:^(BOOL finished) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                playerSliderisScrubbing = NO;
            });
        }];

    }
}
- (float)getCurrentTime {
    float seconds = 0;
    if (_player) {
        seconds = CMTimeGetSeconds([_player currentTime]);
    }
    return seconds;
}
- (float)getPlayerDuration {
    float seconds = 0;
    if (_player) {
        seconds = CMTimeGetSeconds([[_player currentItem] duration]);
    }
    return seconds;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

**Swift 4, 4.2 & 5**

```
var player : AVPlayer!

@IBAction func fastForwardBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let moveForword : Float64 = 5

        if player == nil { return }
        if let duration  = player!.currentItem?.duration {
        let playerCurrentTime = CMTimeGetSeconds(player!.currentTime())
        let newTime = playerCurrentTime + moveForword
        if newTime < CMTimeGetSeconds(duration)
        {
            let selectedTime: CMTime = CMTimeMake(value: Int64(newTime * 1000 as Float64), timescale: 1000)
            player!.seek(to: selectedTime)
        }
        player?.pause()
        player?.play()
        }

    }

@IBAction func rewindBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {
            let moveBackword: Float64 = 5
            if player == nil
            {
                return
            }
            let playerCurrenTime = CMTimeGetSeconds(player!.currentTime())
            var newTime = playerCurrenTime - moveBackword
            if newTime < 0
            {
                newTime = 0
            }
            player?.pause()
            let selectedTime: CMTime = CMTimeMake(value: Int64(newTime * 1000 as Float64), timescale: 1000)
            player?.seek(to: selectedTime)
            player?.play()
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use avPlayer.rate to fast backward/forward

Rates: 1.0 normal
       0.0 pause

But first, you should check if avPlayerItem can do one of your action

For more info: https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVPlayer/rate

Comment: Hello Could you please help me how can I do trick play speed in avplayer bro?

Answer (score 1):

Swift 5 function to seek forwards or backwards

```
private let seekDuration: Float64 = 15
    
private func seekPlayback(isForward: Bool) {
    guard
        let player = player,
        let duration = player.currentItem?.duration
    else {
        return
    }

    let currentElapsedTime = player.currentTime().seconds

    var destinationTime = isForward ? (currentElapsedTime + seekDuration) : (currentElapsedTime - seekDuration)

    if destinationTime < 0 {
        destinationTime = 0
    }

    if destinationTime < duration.seconds {
        let newTime = CMTime(value: Int64(destinationTime * 1000 as Float64), timescale: 1000)
        player.seek(to: newTime)
    }
}
```