# Rewind AVPlayer by 5 seconds

Tags: iphone, ios, stream, avplayer

How can I rewind a stream by 5 second?

This is my code for streaming in the viewDidLoad:

```
AVPlayerItem* playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://groove.wavestreamer.com:7321/listen.pls?sid=1"]];

[playerItem addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"timedMetadata" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];

music = [[AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem] retain];
[music play]; 

music = [[AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem] retain];
[music play];
```

Thanks for your answers...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AVPlayer - Fast Backward / Forward Stream](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15094948/avplayer-fast-backward-forward-stream)

Answer (score 15):

In Swift 3+,

```
fileprivate let seekDuration: Float64 = 5


@IBAction func seekForward(_ sender: Any) {
    guard let duration  = player.currentItem?.duration else {
        return
    }
    let playerCurrentTime = CMTimeGetSeconds(player.currentTime())
    let newTime = playerCurrentTime + seekDuration

    if newTime < (CMTimeGetSeconds(duration) - seekDuration) {

        let time2: CMTime = CMTimeMake(Int64(newTime * 1000 as Float64), 1000)
        player.seek(to: time2, toleranceBefore: kCMTimeZero, toleranceAfter: kCMTimeZero)

    }
}
@IBAction func seekBackward(_ sender: Any) {

    let playerCurrentTime = CMTimeGetSeconds(player.currentTime())
    var newTime = playerCurrentTime - seekDuration

    if newTime < 0 {
        newTime = 0
    }
    let time2: CMTime = CMTimeMake(Int64(newTime * 1000 as Float64), 1000)
     player.seek(to: time2, toleranceBefore: kCMTimeZero, toleranceAfter: kCMTimeZero)


}
```

Answer (score 11):

```
- (NSTimeInterval)currentPlaybackTime
{
    return CMTimeGetSeconds(self.playerView.player.currentItem.currentTime);
}


- (void)setCurrentPlaybackTime:(NSTimeInterval)time
{
    CMTime cmTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(time, NSEC_PER_SEC);
    [self.playerView.player.currentItem seekToTime:cmTime];
}


- (IBAction)scanBackward
{
    self.currentPlaybackTime -= 5.0f;
}
```

Comment: +1, nice and clean. Mind explaining the significance of NSEC_PER_SEC and the "f" units?

Comment: about NSEC_PER_SEC https://developer.apple.com/reference/dispatch/nsec_per_sec?language=objc and the f on 5.0 its for cast it to float

Answer (score 11):

In Swift 5:

```
 @IBAction func seekForward(_ sender: Any) {
    guard let duration  = player?.currentItem?.duration else {
        return
    }
    let playerCurrentTime = CMTimeGetSeconds(player!.currentTime())
    let newTime = playerCurrentTime + 5

    if newTime < (CMTimeGetSeconds(duration) - 5) {

        let time2: CMTime = CMTimeMake(value: Int64(newTime * 1000 as Float64), timescale: 1000)
        player!.seek(to: time2, toleranceBefore: CMTime.zero, toleranceAfter: CMTime.zero)

    }
}

@IBAction func seekBackward(_ sender: Any) {
    let playerCurrentTime = CMTimeGetSeconds(player!.currentTime())
        var newTime = playerCurrentTime - 5

        if newTime < 0 {
            newTime = 0
        }
    let time2: CMTime = CMTimeMake(value: Int64(newTime * 1000 as Float64), timescale: 1000)
    player!.seek(to: time2, toleranceBefore: CMTime.zero, toleranceAfter: CMTime.zero)
}
```